# java date in mmddhhmmss format

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat, date-format

I want to add date to the file so i maintain archive.
I want date in this format: mmddhhmmss

So the file name is "cGroup0307131614", just that i want to add timestamp.
Not necessary it should be mmddhhmmss format but a format that maintains timestamp.

I tried the foll:

```
java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
     System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

But o/p is 2013-03-07 14:59:30.252. I dont want any spaces colons or special characters.

Comment: Don't use `Timestamp`. Do use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =
            new SimpleDateFormat("MMddhhmmss");
String dateAsString = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
System.out.println(dateAsString);
```

Output:

```
0307114712
```

Comment: Timezone is CET in case you get a different result

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime
    .now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
    .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMddHHmmss" ) )
```

## java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes which supplant the old legacy date-time classes.

## `Instant`

Grab the current moment in UTC with the `Instant` class. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();  // UTC
```

May be best to stick with UTC. If so, transform to the more flexible `OffsetDateTime` for formatting. Specify `ZoneOffset.UTC` constant.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

## `DateTimeFormatter`

Define a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for your desired format. I do not recommend leaving out the year, but if you insist, here we go.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMddHHmmss" );
```

Create a String with that formatter.

```
String output = odt.format( f );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Apply a time zone to see the same moment through the lens of a particular region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Use `DateTimeFormatter` to generate a String, as seen above.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).